sys.excepthook AssertionError when trying to start Jupyter server
After having pip installed jupyter on a VM (Linux Ubuntu 22.10, Python 3.10.7), running jupyter notebook gives the error
  File "/home/username/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.app import main
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/app.py", line 17, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.serverapp import flags
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/serverapp.py", line 114, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.services.contents.filemanager import (
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 23, in <module>
    from anyio.to_thread import run_sync
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ._core._sockets import connect_tcp as connect_tcp
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_core/_sockets.py", line 35, in <module>
    from exceptiongroup import ExceptionGroup
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/exceptiongroup/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ._formatting import (
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/exceptiongroup/_formatting.py", line 394, in <module>
    assert sys.excepthook is apport_python_hook.apport_excepthook
AssertionError

I have tried doing
sys.excepthook = sys.__excepthook__

as mentioned here but this doesn't change the output. How do I fix this?

UPDATE:
Upon further digging, it seems that VSCode or Ununtu (not sure which) tries to force the use of sys.excepthook.
Short answer:
You simply need to overwrite the excepthook with a custom excepthook. Then, _formatting.py (which is invoked by IPython, which is invoked by Jupyter) can successfully overwrite sys.excepthook with apport_python_hook.apport_excepthook (I suspect).
As AldegarRızvan states in their answer to a similar issue, just put this code before your import statement of Jupyter and it should work:
import sys

def custom_exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    # Your custom exception handling code here
    print(f"Exception Type: {exctype}\nValue: {value}")

sys.excepthook = custom_exception_hook

# Rest of the code

Note: this only works in a python script, not in an active terminal running python. I suspect the terminal python session is already interactive and, thus, you will be dealing with different issues. See original answer and more details to make it work in a terminal.
More details:
As stated, Jupyter seems to invoke IPython which invokes _formatting.py that has the assert sys.excepthook is apport_python_hook.apport_excepthook line of code. If you put sys.excepthook = apport_python_hook.apport_excepthook in _formatting.py before the assert, then this also works. But that is basically the same as commenting out the assert line.
Inspecting further into apport_python_hook.apport_excepthook, I can see that the issue actually occurs at the if not likely_packaged(binary): line within apport_python_hook.py as it check to see if my working directory starts with a predefined list of strings:
pkg_whitelist = [
    "/bin/",
    "/boot",
    "/etc/",
    "/initrd",
    "/lib",
    "/sbin/",
    "/opt",
    "/usr/",
    "/var",
]

But I am running my code from "/home/..." which is not in this list. This ends the execution by simply returning nothing which results in the assert failing. However, trying to add "/home" to this list causes a slew of different issues. So that didn't work either.
Note: this means that the issue is actually some sort of python3.10/ubuntu 22.10 issue because I can recreate the error by importing BaseExceptionGroup: from exceptiongroup import BaseExceptionGroup.
The answer provided above (short answer) seems to be the most elegant solution at the moment. However, this is only if you are running it in a python script. You likely still have to comment out the assert line if running IPython or Jupyter from a terminal as stated in the original answer.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
I have the exact same setup and error as you. I have looked everywhere and cannot seem to find any other traces of this issue.
I suspect it has to do with Jupyter's dependency on IPython as I get the exact same error when I try to run ipython --pylab in a terminal. I also noticed that I CAN just enter jupyter into the terminal and it does load the help page. But the moment I call jupyter --version, it first says Selected Jupyter core packages... and then starts the traceback.
The only "solution" I have found is to go into the _formatting.py file and comment out the assert sys.excepthook is apport_python_hook.apport_excepthook on line 394. After saving, I am able to spin up an interactive shell in IPython and I can get Jupyter running.
Note: After commenting out the line, I can run jupyter --version in the terminal and look what the output is:
jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.25.0 <---- NOTICE THIS?! (IPyhton package, not version)
ipykernel        : 6.29.4
ipywidgets       : 8.1.2
jupyter_client   : 8.6.1
jupyter_core     : 5.7.2
jupyter_server   : 2.14.0
jupyterlab       : 4.1.6
nbclient         : 0.10.0
nbconvert        : 7.16.3
nbformat         : 5.10.4
notebook         : 7.1.2
qtconsole        : 5.5.1
traitlets        : 5.14.2

IPython is the first package called, which further supports my theory that the issue isn't Jupyter, but rather IPython.
I want to stress, this "solution" is less than ideal and I highly recommend AGAINST doing this, but it may help you/others with troubleshooting.
